# What is the best way to obfuscate/minify dynamically generated javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, apache

I am looking to obfuscate and minify dynamically written javascript with ruby.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Some kind of apache module that would intercept the .js file and obfuscate it before it was served would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.rb

A javascript minifier implemented in ruby.

Hope it helps...

Comment: found using wayback machine http://web.archive.org/web/20090130033740/http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.rb